How exactly is initdb called when installing PostgreSQL from its official installer
Background context: I'm currently trying to figure out by myself how to change the LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE values of a freshly initialized PostgreSQL cluster (having only the postgres, template1 and template0 databases in it -- and from what I've read until now*, it's not trivial, especially for the template0, the other two can be easily dropped/recreated).
This led me to ask myself this very naive question:
how exactly is initdb called (with which parameters) when actually installing PostgreSQL using the official installer on Windows?
(I guess the same initdb command is executed on Debian based systems when installing the postgresql apt package, right?)
* https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396581
* https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279796
* https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html

I don't know, but I simply delete the cluster that the installer created automatically. Then I can call initdb myself with all the options I want.
